# Can we use save transaction command only in nested transactions?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I am a newbie to SQL and I came across a situation where I have to use save transaction, but can any one please let me know if save transaction should only be used in nested transactions ? If not what is the difference between having a save point and not having a save point transaction in a Stored procedure where we don't use nested transactions ?

Thanks !!

Answer (score 2):

> I am a newbie to SQL and I came across a situation where I have to use save transaction

Savepoints are rarely used (or useful) and it's unusual that "a newbie" would "have to use save transaction".

> what is the difference between having a save point and not having a save point transaction in a Stored procedure where we don't use nested transactions

Save Points allow partial rollback.